# Associate a tab in Google Chrome with its process in task manager

Tags: google-chrome, memory, process

How do I identify which process belongs to which tab in Google Chrome?

Normally, I have a (ridiculously) large number of tabs open.  If I need to free memory on my box, I would like to choose based on tab/process memory footprint.

Comment: I also have run into the same issue and glad there a number of good answers. I usually exit Chrome (Menu -> Exit) and restart. All tabs and windows reopen quick and with fresh process memory.

Comment: I used to open windows taskmanager and hover over my chrome tab to see which process would show activity :) Good question, good answers, thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Chrome has it's own in-built task manager which makes it easy to identify which process belongs to which tab(s). You can access it by the hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or by right clicking on the title bar and selecting "Task Manager".

Chrome also has a more detailed memory page which can be accessed by opening a new tab and entering `chrome://system/` into the omnibox.

Comment: What is the hotkey for the task manager on a Mac?

Comment: @Kevin According to this post there isn't one by default. But this page explains how to set your own. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xz-9TlEwwCc

Comment: @Kevin: no hotkey, but it’s accessible under the “Window” menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, `chrome://memory-redirect` has been removed (https://codereview.chromium.org/1722493002)

Answer (score 8):

You have to just **right click** and you will get the **Task Manager** for Google Chrome

This is a feature given by Chrome so that you can easily see and tab and also you can close the tab and get the detail of the tab

The detail is given below in the form of figure

[image]

Comment: Nice screenshot.

Comment: I always knew it was there, but I had no idea the Chrome Task Manager was so easy to get to.  Thanks.

Comment: In Windows 7, right-clicking alone did not bring up the context menu as in your screenshot, it brought up a list of frequently visited and pinned tabs. I had to shift-right click to bring up the version that you show here.

Answer (score 5):

In chrome go to the Menu → Tools → Task Manager.

This will bring up a list of all the tabs, background processes, plugins, overall Chrome process, etc...

If you right click in this window you can have it display the OS process ID associated with each tab.  This should you allow you to compare that to the process ID in windows task manager, top, or whatever you use to view processes.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Shift+Esc, you will get the process manager then you can kill the processes, select the desired one (You'll see the title from the website on the tab), and just click "End process", Sort it by private memory (with the arrow pointing down), so you will see the most consuming tabs first..